# Accessing SharePoint API to insert data to list from a Asp.Net project

Tags: asp.net, azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

We have been trying to insert data to a SharePoint list from a ASP.net project. We are using following API code to access the SharePoint list that we have found from SharePoint documentations. We are getting unauthorized status when we try the code.

```
 var vendorName = $("#ddlVendorName").val();
                var date = $("#date").val();
                var contractorType = $("#contractorType").val();
                $.ajax
                    ({`enter code here`
                        url: "https://siteurl/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/items",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify
                            ({
                                Vendor: vendorName,
                                ContractorType: contractorType,
                                Date: date
                            }),
                        headers:
                            {
                                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                                "X-HTTP-Method": "POST",
                                "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
                            },
                        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                            alert('success');
                            retriveListItem();
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            alert('fail');
                            // $("#ResultDiv").empty().text(data.responseJSON.error);
                        } 
                    });
```

We also tried to get the list details using Postman. Then we are getting following message

{"error_description":"Unsupported security token."}

Is this the correct way of accessing SharePoint details using API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you get the token, while you should register your application as Add-in and then get the token, below thread shares detailed sample for this, I think it would help you.

http://spshell.blogspot.com/2015/03/sharepoint-online-o365-oauth.html